# Access VBAについて教えて下さい。

Tags: vba, ms-access

テキストボックスX1～Y1に数字(整数)を入力して、総和を求めたいです。
x1□～y1□　総和□　ボタン□

```
Private Sub btnWa_Click()
　
    Dim lSouwa As Long

    lSouwa = 0

    For  lSouwa = txtX1 To txtY1
           lSouwa = txtX1 + txtY1
    Next

    txtSouwa.Value = lSouwa

End sub
```

一応、書いてはみましたが…。正しいプログラムを教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

以前、@ITのサイトで　[Access VBAで学ぶ初心者のためのデータベース／SQL超入門](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1505/27/news020.html)　という連載（全12回）がありました（現在も閲覧可能です）。
Accessのフォームの作り方、VBAによるフォームの操作・利用、SQLなどについて、とても判りやすい記事なので、一読されることをお勧めします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。見てみます。